# Asp.net core uses ORM tools for database migration

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to asp.net core, different languages may have their own dataset migration framework. In asp.net core, how do I migrate my mysql fields to my project? In the past, the fields of the model class were written and mapped to the database. Now, how to map the database to the model class? I found this article, but please tell me how to do it, forgive my question.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is database-first approach;
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/database-first-approach-in-entity-framework/#:~:text=Database%20First%20Approach%20creates%20the,between%20the%20database%20and%20controller.

Comment: edmx is not included in EF Core, You need to do reverse engineering

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a demo of mapping from database to model, you can refer to it.

First, here are the Nuget packages needed:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.22" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.22">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.22">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.22" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Then enter this command to generate the model file you need.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "mysql connection" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models
```

You need to fill in your database connection address, and choose which directory you output to. My side is the Models directory.

Creating a Connector/NET Connection String:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html

Table in mysql:

[image]

The final generated file:

[image]

```
 public partial class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Pwd { get; set; }
    }
```

You can refer to this article:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-scaffold-example.html